# is there any way to watch sms activity(receive not send) in iphone

Tags: ios4

is there any way to watch sms activity(receive, not send) in iphone

Answer (score 1):

- Download "message composer"sample (XCode project) from developer iPhone web page.
- You can´t get events from message app directly but you can use their SMS editor. Check the XCode project out.

the function is :

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller 
              didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: SMS sending canceled";
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: SMS sent";
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: SMS sending failed";
            break;
        default:
            feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: SMS not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is definitely not available with any of the APIs in the iOS SDK. I would assume there's a way if you were to jailbreak, but obviously Apple would not allow this in the App Store.